# Can I use the Airport Express as a an uplink between two networks?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, airport-express

I have two separate networks using different IP ranges, 192.168.0.* for the wired only, isolated network and 192.160.1.* for the wireless only network which is connected to the internet.

The wired network has a network printer setup and working and I want to be able to share it out to members of the wireless network (see diagram below).

In short I need some kind of uplink between the two networks. Currently running a cable is out since there is no suitable route.

I have a spare Airport Express and I am wondering if I could attach it to the wired network and have it join the wireless and act as the uplink between the two. Anyone know if the device is capable of this?

[image: Current network layout]

Comment: Does your existing wireless router support [WDS](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4262)?

Comment: (If so, set up WDS. But remember, you cannot have a DHCP server on two networks and then bridge them.)

Comment: The router currently at 192.168.1.1 does not support WDS.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, it won't work. Since the router at 192.168.1.1 doesn't support WDS, the only type of connection you can make is a WiFi client connection. And you cannot bridge to a WiFi client connection because the WiFi specification prohibits it.

There are some "hacks" that get around this, such as the "client bridging" mode some aftermarket firmwares support. But they won't work in this case because the router can't masquerade as a host on a network that it itself is not on. (So you can use them to bridge two segments of the same network with some caveats, but not two different IP networks.)